# How to save multiple files uploaded using FileInput in Python Panel?

Tags: python, panel, dashboard

I created a working code to upload multiple files using FileInput, and I binded it to a selector to show them in the dashboard after uploading:

```
file_input = pn.widgets.FileInput(accept='.csv', sizing_mode='stretch_width',
                                  multiple=True)

def get_files(files = None):
    if file_input.filename == None:
        selector = pn.widgets.MultiSelect(
        name='Select files', sizing_mode='stretch_width',
        options=['Add your files here'])
        return selector
    else:
        breakpoint()
        selector = pn.widgets.MultiSelect(
        name='Select files', sizing_mode='stretch_width',
        options=file_input.filename)
        return selector

upload_files = pn.bind(get_files,file_input, watch= True)
```

I can see the filenames there:
(Pdb) file_input.filename
['test_5.csv', 'test_4.csv', 'test_3.csv', 'test_2.csv', 'test.csv']

But the save method only works for me when I have uploaded only one file:

(Pdb) out = io.BytesIO()
(Pdb) file_input.save(out)
*** TypeError: FileInput contains a single files but a list of filenames was given. Please provide a single filename or file-like object.

I could not find anything useful reading FileInput documentation.

Someones give me an working method to save multiple files using FileInput.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself, you need to provide a list of files, file_input.filename works fine.
I think a list of io.BytesIO() objects would also work.